# Apache giving "No such file or directory" error when trying to run cgi

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cgi

```
No such file or directory: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/haml.cgi' failed
```

Is the main error I'm getting right now. Trying to run a custom CGI, the cgi currently works successfully on another server I have, but it seems I've overlooked some configuration option on this server.

I have the cgi-bin directory set to allow CGI execution:

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've set the perms of haml.cgi to 777, simply to eliminate any permission issue from being the problem:

```
root@jp:/usr/lib/cgi-bin# ls -lah

total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root www-data 4.0K Aug 14 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 64 root root     4.0K Oct 28  2014 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root www-data  505 Aug 14 18:20 haml.cgi
```

I have cgid enabled:

```
root@jp:/etc/apache2# ls mods-enabled/
access_compat.load  alias.load       authz_core.load  autoindex.load  deflate.load  filter.load     mpm_event.load    setenvif.load
actions.conf        auth_basic.load  authz_host.load  cgid.conf       dir.conf      mime.conf       negotiation.conf  status.conf
actions.load        authn_core.load  authz_user.load  cgid.load       dir.load      mime.load       negotiation.load  status.load
alias.conf          authn_file.load  autoindex.conf   deflate.conf    env.load      mpm_event.conf  setenvif.conf
```

And my site itself is set up to exec cgi:

```
DocumentRoot /home/j/web/
DirectoryIndex index.haml index.html
<Directory "/home/j/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Am I missing anything here? Any idea why the CGI isn't running?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up actually being my ruby installation that was giving me issues. Running the cgi directly showed me this:

```
root@jp:/usr/lib/cgi-bin# ./haml.cgi
bash: ./haml.cgi: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Nice! This puts an end to my own search. Don't be too proud to accept your answer.

Comment: I had similar issue with Python script. The interpreter was not `#!/usr/bin/python` but it was `#!/usr/bin/python3`. I realized when I ran CGI separately and got bad interpreter error